# SVM classifier convergence

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, classification, svm, convergence

I was implementing a SVM Classifier using `scikit` library on a [MNIST dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/digit-recognizer) available on Kaggle. Everything was going well until one of my friend asked me a question:

> What is the number of updates required before the SVM classifier converges?

I got stuck here. How can I answer this?

Comment: By "updates" and "converges" do you mean: to the local optimum (for the dataset)? or what is the convergence to the optimum for the actual distribution?

Comment: I think convergence is related to convergence of optimisation function. And updates means how many times we need to rotate or shift the hyperplane to reach optimisation.

Answer (score 2):

This is highly dependant on the algorithm in question. Optimizers such as SMO are basically doing a matrix inversion and may have run time $O(n^3)$ in the worst case. Recent approaches are much faster, and are generally stochastic and often use variance reduction techniques. There are numerous of these: SAGA, SVRG, SPDC, etc.

Generally, in these works, they have several iterations where in each iteration they do a small amount of work (i.e., $O(d)$ where $d$ is the dimension of the problem); and in the end they take some (possibly weighted) average over the individual iterates. The number of iterates is generally $O\left( (n + f(\kappa, n)) \log \frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)$ to reach $\epsilon$ convergence, where $f(\cdot,\cdot)$ depends on the algorithm, for example $\kappa$ or $\sqrt{\kappa n}$.  $\kappa$ is the condition number ($\frac{R^2}{\lambda\gamma}$) where our points lie in an $R^2$ sphere, and our  function to minimize is $(1/\gamma)$-Lischitz smooth and $\lambda$-strongly convex. There is also work around non-strongly convex functions (i.e., $\lambda=0$).

Here are some links:

[SPDC](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume18/16-568/16-568.pdf)

[SAGA, SVRG and more](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.04838.pdf)

Comment: How will you implement it sklearn and find the number of updates on MNIST

Comment: From the scikit documentation - http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html#sklearn.svm.SVC The implementation is based on libsvm. The fit time complexity is more than quadratic with the number of samples which makes it hard to scale to dataset with more than a couple of 10000 samples. Note that libsvm is SMO baed implementation - so this is O(n^3) in the worst case.

Comment: What if I use SGDclassifier as SVM instead of  SVC from scikit?

Comment: That's a plain SGD - so $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$